# how to simulate a click event on page load to a php file

Tags: php, click, pageload, simulate

i have been trying to figure out how to simulate a click event and pass it to a php file.

i want a click to passed to the following url on page load without any user interaction means on page load event.

```
http://www.xyz.com/jq.php?href=http://www.abc.com/xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use good old HTTP for that (which is also very search engine friendly), either with PHP:

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://www.xyz.com/jq.php?href=http://www.abc.com/xyz");
```

Or via .htaccess, with something like this (which works the same way, I guess):

```
## redirect index.php to the new domain
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.xyz.com/jq.php?href=http://www.abc.com/xyz
```

Or something like this (if you're on an Apache and have mod_rewrite enabled):

```
RewriteEngine on
## redirect everything to the new domain:
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xyz.com/jq.php?href=http://www.abc.com/xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
```